# Android mockito mocking callback

Tags: java, android

I am testing an interactor that returns a callback to a class.
here is the code -

Presenter

```
public MyPresenter() implements MyInteractorCallback {
    MyInteractorImpl interactorImpl = new MyInteractorImpl(this);

    interactorImpl.doSomething(obj);

    @Override
    public void statusChange(String status) {
      //.....
    }
}
```

InteractorImpl

```
public MyInteractorImpl() {

MyInteractorCallback callback;

public MyInteractorImpl(final MyInteractorCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void doSomething(MyObj obj) {
      callback.statusChange("OK");
      //....
      callback.statusChange("NO");
    }
}
```

InteractorCallback

```
Interface MyInteractorCallback {
   void statusChange(String status);
}
```

MyTest

```
@Test
    public void testMyObj() {
        obj = new MyObj();
        callback = mock(MyInteractorCallback.class);
        MyInteractorImpl impl = new MyInteractorImpl(callback);
        impl.doSomething(obj);
        verify(callback).statusChange("NO");
    }
```

This throws me an error -

```
Wanted but not invoked:
callback.statusChange(
    OK
);

However, there was exactly 2 interaction with this mock:
```

What exactly is this error? How can i get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

That error should mean that you have somewhere in your testcode you run verify(callback).statuschange("OK"). Maybe you have mixed up OK and NO somewhere?